# looping an array, only do something when an attribute of the loop changes

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

In an foreach loop I am doing, I am building an array of URLS, I want to build this add to this array of urls every loop and then do something with that new array when attribute on the loop changes....for example, I am looping a dataset that contains an URL and a post_id, I want to keep adding URLS to a new array until the post id changes at which point I want save the new array (I can do this logic) and clear out the new array to be used again.

At the moment I have,

```
$new_array = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {

    $new_array[] = $result->url;
    $curr_id = $result->post_id;
    if($curr_id != $result->post_id) {
        $new_array = [];
    }
}
```

My attempt above I always feel with return false as $curr_id will always equal the $result->post_id, but I don't know where else I could set it to watch for a change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood but perhaps like so:

```
$new_array = [];
$out=[];      // store urls here when id changes
$curr_id=-1;  // create a value you know will not be viable

foreach( $results as $result ) {
    /* will be invoked on 1st iteration and subsequent iterations when post_id changes */
    if( $curr_id != $result->post_id ) {

        /* change the var to new post_id */
        $curr_id = $result->post_id;

        /* if the array is not empty at this point, save it to output array */
        if( !empty( $new_array ) )$out[]=$new_array;

        /* create new array to store urls */
        $new_array = [];
    }

    $new_array[] = $result->url;
}
```